# De-duplicate a key-value text file by key

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file with key-value properties, e.g.:

```
foo: aaa
bla: hello
bar: bbb
foo: ccc
bar: ddd
```

I want to deduplicate the file, only keep the last appearance of a key, in this example the result would be:

```
bla: hello
foo: ccc
bar: ddd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in script:

```
# recreate input
cat <<EOF >input_file.txt
foo: aaa
bla: hello
bar: bbb
foo: ccc
bar: ddd
EOF

# add line number on front
nl -w1 -s: input_file.txt |
# tac the script to keep the latest key
tac |
# sort unique on keys
sort -t: -k2,2 -u |
# sort on line numbers, to restore original numeration
sort -t: -k1,1 -n |
# remove line numbers
cut -d: -f2-
```

it will output:

```
bla: hello
foo: ccc
bar: ddd
```

If however you don't need original order, you can just:

```
tac input_file.txt | sort -t: -u -k1,1
```

that will output:

```
bar: ddd
bla: hello
foo: ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=": "} {dict[$1] = $2} END{for (i in dict) print i, dict[i]}' file
```

```
foo: ccc
bla: hello
bar: ddd
```

Keep in mind that order of keys in output may vary.

---

To keep same order as shown in question use `tac + awk + tac`:

```
tac file | awk -F ': ' '!seen[$1]++' | tac
```

```
bla: hello
foo: ccc
bar: ddd
```